# exporting mysql data to ODF with php

Tags: php, mysql, openoffice.org, odf, opendocument

I would like to know if someone triend exporting data from MySQL to an ODF format ?

Any information / documentation would be very much appreciated.

I am going to try to export a MySQL result set to ODF spreadsheet if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You could try looking at this: http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/4398.html

However looking at the source code it doesn't look great and has lots of hard coded xml strings

Answer (score 1):

Another option to create OOo files with PHP is [tbsOOo](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/tbsooo.php); however, it is mainly a templating engine.

> This class allows to create OpenOffice
>   documents dynamically by separating
>   display formatting from logic and
>   data. In practice, you create a
>   template using OpenOffice with the
>   TinyButStrong tags. Then you create a
>   PHP script that merges the template
>   with a data source to get a new
>   OpenOffice document.

There is also: [OpenDocument PHP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opendocumentphp/) which is more complex and can create the files dynamically.